# I am using aspose-words library in java to read word document and to report page number. It is working fine in windows but not in UNIX how can i fix?

Tags: java, unix, ms-word, aspose, aspose.words

I am using LayoutCollector in aspose-words library to get the page number of a node.

```
Document document=new Document(filePath);
LayoutCollector layoutCollector=new LayoutCollector(doc);
NodeCollection paragraphNodes=document.getChildNodes(NodeType.Paragraph,true);
for(Node node:paragraphNodes)
{
 if(node.getType==NodeType.PARAGRAPH){
 int pageNumber=layoutCollector.getStartPageIndex(node);
System.out.println(pageNumber);
}
```

While i am getting the exact page number in my local windows system but not in UNIX server. it is wrongly reporting the page numbers. Any reason for such behaviour, How can i fix this issue?

Comment: I don't know this api but maybe something to do with different line separators in Unix? (`\n` instead of `\r\n`)

Comment: I am not using any logic to extract paragraphs on my own i am using inbuilt method to get paragraph text and page number. It is absolutely working fine in my windows machine but not in UNIX server. I am using same jar in both

Comment: Even so, that's the reason that first springs to mind. Maybe there's a setting in the api you haven't noticed... If you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I'll test it on my (Unix) machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in Unix environment might occur because the fonts used in the source document are not available in the environment where the document is processed. To calculate page number of the node Aspose.Words need to build document layout. Upon building document layout, if Aspose.Words cannot find the fonts used in the document the [fonts are substituted](https://docs.aspose.com/words/java/manipulate-and-substitute-truetype-fonts/). This might lead into the layout difference, since substitution fonts might have different font metrics. In turn, this might lead to incorrect page numbers detection by `LayoutCollector`. You can implement [IWarningCallback](https://reference.aspose.com/words/java/com.aspose.words/iwarningcallback/) to get a notification when font substitution is performed.

The following articles can be useful for you:

https://docs.aspose.com/words/java/specify-truetype-fonts-location/

https://docs.aspose.com/words/java/install-truetype-fonts-on-linux/

Comment: I am facing this issue while running in server(i.e UNIX). How can i fix this issue ? after running my jar in UNIX i have to get the report that have page numbers and mask the data in word document it is mismatching.

Comment: You should install or provide the fonts required to render the document to get an accurate page numbers detection.